# Can controllers be completely replaced by the link function in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was reading through this article:

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html

Which proposes that controllers be integrated into directives like this in order to remove the need to ever use ng-controller:

```
angular.module('contestantEditor', [])
  .directive('cContestantEditorForm', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        contestants: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'contestant_editor.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'ContestantEditorFormCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true
    };
  })
  .controller('ContestantEditorFormCtrl', function($scope) {

    this.contestant = {};

    this.save = function() {
      this.contestants.push(this.contestant);
      this.contestant = {};
    };

  });
```

In the comments, however, someone else proposed this solution:

```
angular.module('contestantEditor', [])
  .directive('cContestantEditorForm', function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        contestants: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'contestant_editor.html',
      replace: true,
      link: function (scope) {
        scope.contestant = {};

        scope.save = function() {
          scope.contestants.push(scope.contestant);
          scope.contestant = {};
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

It achieves the exact same thing as the version with the controller without ever needing to make a controller. So I'm curious as to what the pros and cons of either method are versus writing angular traditionally with ng-controller, and whether controllers are even necessary by the end of it.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2wq7j?p=preview) is the plunker for the first, and [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqi4U8?p=preview) is the second.

Answer (score 4):

In **directives**, you should use *link function* whenever you can. Use *controllers* only when communication to other directives is needed.

You can find more about this discussion [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate). Specifically this best practice statement:

> **Best Practice**: *use **controller** when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use **link**.*

Answer (score -1):

*Directives and  Controllers are two totally different things.*

**Direvtives should be used for DOM manipulations.**

if you want to know use controller inside DDO or use link function for your logic, then answer will be you should use controller in DDO in that cases when you want provide API and require your directive in other directives and use that API in extended directive

---

**Controllers can't be replaced by directive**

Controller should contain your businesses logic and it cant be replaced by directive and shouldn't have DOM manipulations.

Comment: Regarding "controllers can't be replaced by directive," did you read the article? They didn't get rid of controllers, but rather integrated them into their directives. It works almost exactly the same as normal, but removes the need for ng-controller or even having a scope through the "bindToController" attribute. Could you revise your answer so it more specifically addresses integrating controllers into directives?

Comment: No but I will, yes the second part about that